# Python proper hierarchy of abstract classes

Tags: python, abstract-class, abstract, abc

I have the next code defined below.
This sample has a 2 architcet problems:

1. Concrete class `Post` has a warning because doesn't implement (it's impossible) some abstract methods
2. Abstract class are inheritor of concrete class.

I know a few solutions but they all are not perfect:

1. Remove abstract classes at all.
2. Remove intermediate `LogicA` (`Post`) class at all.
3. Make multiple inheritance for final classes (may not help but apparently will reduce damage)
4. Split this classes in a huge amount of small classes.

Why they all are not perfect:

1. I need abstract classes because this methods as alias use another classes (dependency injection)
2. Will force me to repeat a code in every final concrete class, violates DRY
3. Multiple inheritance are evil
4. Will easily increase number of classes X2, from 6 to ~(12-18

The common hierarchy is:

Base abstract class `AbstractA` with methods which has every FINAL subclass ->

Concrete class `LogicA` (inheritor of `AbstractA` class)  that partially implements methods which has a common logic and exactly the same code inside ->

Another abstract class `FinalAbstractA` (inheritor of `LogicA`) with some specific abstract methods only for this class ->

Another abstract class `FinalAbstractB` (inheritor of `LogicA`) with some specific abstract methods only for this class ->

Final concrete class `FinalLogicA` (inheritor of `FinalAbstractA`).

Final concrete class `FinalLogicB` (inheritor of `FinalAbstractB`).

In short:
`AbstractA -> LogicA -> (FinalAbstractA -> FinalLogicA + FinalAbstractB -> FinalLogicB)`

```
class AbstractPost(ABC):
    """Abstract Intermediate class with common methods for all inheritors"""
    @abstractmethod  # Method that has every final inheritor but not an intermediate
    def read(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod  # A common method for all subclasses
    def post_from_callback(cls, current_user: classes.users.User, callback: CallbackQuery) -> Post | None:
        raise NotImplementedError


class Post(AbstractPost):  # Warning on this line that not all abstract methods defined.
    """
    Implementation of intermediate class with common methods for all inheritors
    This class not supposing to has an instances, only type hint
    "read" function can't be implemented here because `post` instanse not defined in DB doesn't has. 
    "read" function has a common signature but should be impleneted in concrete class because has different sql queries.
    """
    @classmethod
    def post_from_callback(cls, current_user: classes.users.User, callback: CallbackQuery) -> Post | None:
        post = cls.read(user=current_user, post_id=abs(int(callback.data.split()[-1])))
        if post is not None and post.validate(data=int(callback.data.split()[-2])):
            return post


class AbstractPublicPost(Post):
    """Abstract class with some methods which has only this class"""
    @abstractmethod
    def public_post_method_only(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class PublicPost(AbstractPublicPost):
    """Implementation of abstract class with some  methods which has only this class"""
    def public_post_method_only(self):
        ...


class AbstractPersonalPost(Post):
    """Abstract class with some methods which has only this class"""
    @abstractmethod
    def personal_post_method_only(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class PersonalPost(AbstractPersonalPost):
    """Implementation of abstract class with some  methods which has only this class"""
    def personal_post_method_only(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Intermediate classes that aren't intended to be instantiated should be made abstract as well.

Comment: @Barmar. Can you provide a link for how to do that? Technically `class Post` is still abstract because it inherits some abstract methods.

Comment: Good question. I guess you could add duplicate `@abstractmethod` in `Post`.

Comment: Any class that has unimplemented abstract methods is still an abstract class, just not a base class.  Documenting that it should not be instantiated, and then letting error occur if a user tries to is sufficient.

Comment: Is `AbstractPost` being inherited anywhere else other than in `Post` (other code not shown)?

Comment: Please provide "warning" you are getting as well. This code executes without warnings (with `annotations` future, of course) and almost passes `mypy` typechecking (with unrelated errors + obviously bad `read` method call signature in `Post.post_from_callback -> cls.read`). If it is some IDE warning, just ignore it - it is a false positive. Your `Post` class is absolutely fine, it is abstract class with one abstract method `read`.

Comment: See [this pycharm issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19236/Class-must-implement-all-abstract-methods-inspection-should-be-changed) regarding such false-positive warnings.

Comment: Thanks for the activity! 1. I got a common opinion to move Post into AbstractPost. 2. The warning is a warning of Pycharm, I'm not using a Mypy because Pycharm covers it mostly AFAIK. 3. In the code no instances of Post class at all. 4. This is my personal code, not a library, but I suppose it may become a library at some moment. 
5. Posted code are only a sample, indeed every class has much more methods.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are over complicating this.  Just because a class is a base class, does not mean you cannot implement a method, which is then inherited by other classes.

You could move `post_from_callback` from `Post` to `AbstractPost` with no issues and eliminate `Post` altogether.

```py
class AbstractPost(ABC):
    """Abstract Intermediate class with common methods for all inheritors"""
    @abstractmethod
    def read(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def post_from_callback(cls, current_user: classes.users.User, callback: CallbackQuery):
        post = cls().read(user=current_user, post_id=abs(int(callback.data.split()[-1])))
        if post is not None and post.validate(data=int(callback.data.split()[-2])):
            return post


class AbstractPublicPost(AbstractPost):
    """Abstract subclass for public posts"""
    @abstractmethod
    def public_post_method_only(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class PublicPost(AbstractPublicPost):
    def public_post_method_only(self):
        ...


class AbstractPersonalPost(AbstractPost):
    """Abstract subclass for personal posts."""
    @abstractmethod
    def personal_post_method_only(self):
        pass


class PersonalPost(AbstractPersonalPost):
    def personal_post_method_only(self):
        ...
```

Comment: If this is library code or other reusable stuff, then the original solution is better: it just declares the interface with abstract methods, allowing users to choose whether they like `post_from_callback` implementation or want something else. It is not strictly necessary (override in subclass without `super()` call will work), but is a good sign that this method can be re-implemented and the original class does not rely on its side effects, if any.

Comment: `Post` was basically acting as a mixin class to add one method, but it is implemented in all of the subsequent subclasses.  This much hierarchy adds complexity without much benefit.  If having a minimal public interface is really important, it might be better off to use a `Protocol` class.  We are just swapping coding opinions at this point.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Well, it is probably a matter of taste. `Protocol` will be an excellent fit here in typed context, but will not prevent users from subclassing without implementation of desired methods if they don't use `mypy` (`pyre`, `pyright`, ...). As long as python doesn't enforce annotations (and it was mentioned multiple times that this will never happen, fortunately), it is less strict. I really like OP original class hierarchy and will be glad to see such solutions in real libraries (except for naming, `AbstractBasePost` and `AbstractPost` would be more intuitive).